# JSON serialization error when creating a Luigi task graph

Tags: python, json, serialization, jupyter, luigi

I'm trying to batch up the processing of a few Jupyter notebooks using Luigi, and I've run into a problem.

I have two classes. The first, `transform.py`:

```
import nbformat
import nbconvert

import luigi
from nbconvert.preprocessors.execute import CellExecutionError


class Transform(luigi.Task):
    """Foo."""
    notebook = luigi.Parameter()
    requirements = luigi.ListParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return self.requirements

    def run(self):
        nb = nbformat.read(self.notebook, nbformat.current_nbformat)
        # https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html
        ep = nbconvert.preprocessors.ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
        try:
            ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': "/".join(self.notebook.split("/")[:-1])}})
            with self.output().open('w') as f:
                nbformat.write(nb, f)
        except CellExecutionError:
            pass  # TODO

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.notebook)
```

This defines a Luigi task that takes a notebook as input (along with possible prior requirements to running this task) and ought to run that notebook and report a success or failure as output.

To run `Transform` tasks I have a tiny `Runner` class:

```
import luigi


class Runner(luigi.Task):
    requirements = luigi.ListParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return self.requirements
```

To run my little job, I do:

```
from transform Transform
trans = Transform("../tests/fixtures/empty_valid_errorless_notebook.ipynb", []) 
from runner import Runner
run_things = Runner([trans])
```

But this raises `TypeError: Object of type 'Transform' is not JSON serializable`!

Is my `luigi` task format correct? If so, is it obvious what component in `run` is making the entire class unserializable? If not, how should I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requires()` is supposed to return a task or tasks, not a parameter.

e.g.,

```
class Runner(luigi.Task):
  notebooks = luigi.ListParameter()

  def requires(self):
    required_tasks = []  
    for notebook in self.notebooks:
      required_tasks.append(Transform(notebook))
    return required_tasks

class Transform(luigi.Task):
   notebook = luigi.Parameter()

   def requires(self):
      return []

# then to run at cmd line
luigi --module YourModule Runner --noteboooks '["notebook1.pynb","notebook2.pynb"]'
```

Comment: So it's not possible to not hard-code dependencies ahead of time?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you can hard-code it, I was just point out what the expected return type of the requires() method is. Let me know if you need another example.

Comment: I want to programatically create a new task at runtime, passing down any additional requirements going even further back from above. So suppose I decide, at run-time, that my task graph is Transform("a.ipynb") --> Transform("b.ipynb") --> Runner. Runner would need to be able to create a `trans_a = Transform("a.ipynb", requirements=[])` as well as `Transform("b.ipynb", requirements=[trans_a])`. If I can't write to the `requirements` parameter as a variable, I'm not sure how I can go about doing that (without file I/O trickery at least).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "at runtime". You would pass in the list of notebooks and other parameters needed to dynamically generate tasks, not the tasks themselves as parameters.

Comment: I totally understand OP, he wants the dependencies of the tasks to be defined at task chaining time, not at task code writting time, e.g. he wants reusable tasks with dynamic dependencies, I am facing the exact same problem and I am pretty sure it is solvable.